# proper data type for the input "978-0-590-55411-4"

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

If I input this "978-0-590-55411-4" should my data type be "varchar"?. Because it wont work with int as it output an error that please enter a valid number.

Comment: Will the value ever start with a zero (i.e. something like `078-0-590-55411-4`? Is it always that exact length? Will it be used for numeric calculations?

Comment: Of course it's an error for int - it's not an int. Ints don't contain embedded hyphens. Your only alternative is Char (if it will always be the same length) or VarChar (if the length varies).